# I'm not understanding 2D arrays well enough

Tags: vb.net

I have a 2D array made in Visual Basic and the array is already populated with values for up to 3 indices. The code I have adds up the sum of each row and each column but I don't understand how this works when I have only changed the order of the For loops.

```
Dim columnTotal As Integer
Dim rowTotal As Integer
For row = 0 To 2
    For col = 0 To 2
        rowTotal += magicSquare(col, row)
    Next
    MsgBox("Row " & row & " " & rowTotal)
    rowTotal = 0
Next
For col = 0 To 2
    For row = 0 To 2
        columnTotal += magicSquare(col, row)
    Next
    MsgBox("Column " & col & " " & columnTotal)
    columnTotal = 0
Next
```

I want to know how the For loops are traversing the 2D array and how, by just changing the order of the For loop, to find the sum of the columns I get the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it'd be easier to visualize if you printed the values that are being summed prior to performing the operation:

```
Imports System
Public Module Module1
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim magicSquare = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}
        Dim columnTotal As Integer
        Dim rowTotal As Integer
        For row As Integer = 0 To 2
            For col As Integer = 0 To 2
                rowTotal += magicSquare(col, row)
                Console.WriteLine("    row: {0}, column: {1}: {2}", row, col, magicSquare(col, row))
            Next
            Console.WriteLine("Row {0}: {1}" , row, rowTotal) : Console.WriteLine()
            rowTotal = 0
        Next
        For col As Integer = 0 To 2
            For row As Integer = 0 To 2
                columnTotal += magicSquare(col, row)
                Console.WriteLine("    column: {0}, row {1}: {2}", col, row, magicSquare(col, row))
            Next
            Console.WriteLine("Column {0}: {1}" , col, columnTotal) : Console.WriteLine()
            columnTotal = 0
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

Live Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/1Osand

With the first nested loop you're adding all of the values in a row whereas the second loop is adding all of the values in a column. Ultimately you're looping through all of the items, the difference is how/what you're performing your addition on.

P.S. - My last response was a little rushed so I can elaborate a little bit more now. In your first nested loop you are essentially saying: I want to loop through every row, then I want to add every value in that row, and finally I want to print the results.

In the second nested loop you're doing the same thing only in reverse, you are essentially saying: I want to loop through every column, then I want to add every value in that column, and finally I want to print the results.

So by changing the nested order of the loop, you change the context. If you read (as in you interpret) the code from the outermost loop to the innermost you could say: I am looping through every row and adding every value in the row or I am looping through every column and adding every value in the column.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in VB.Net, 2D arrays have the first index as the row, and the second as the column i.e. `array[row,col]` (unlike VBA which is the inverse). Because of this, I will call your row COL, and col ROW. Hope it's not confusing... In the first loop, the COL = 0 while ROW = 0, 1, 2

If this is your array,

```
Dim magicSquare = {{2, 7, 6}, {9, 5, 1}, {4, 3, 8}}
' or
Dim magicSquare =
{
    {2, 7, 6}, ' first index = 0
    {9, 5, 1}, ' first index = 1
    {4, 3, 8} '  first index = 2
} ' you can see why the first index corresponds to the row, not col
```

then the values being added are `magicArray(0, 0) + magicArray(1, 0) + magicArray(2, 0)` or `2 + 9 + 4 = 15`. Then the COL = 1 while ROW = 0, 1, 2. Lastly, COL = 2 while ROW = 0, 1, 2. It can be visualized

```
    {
        {2, _, _},
        {9, _, _},
        {4, _, _}
    }
    {
        {_, 7, _},
        {_, 5, _},
        {_, 3, _}
    }
    {
        {_, _, 6},
        {_, _, 1},
        {_, _, 8}
    }
```

Then you just switch it up so ROW = 0 while COL = 0, 1, 2 then ROW = 1 while COL = 0, 1, 2 then ROW = 2 while COL = 0, 1, 2.

```
    {
        {2, 7, 6},
        {_, _, _},
        {_, _, _}
    }
    {
        {_, _, _},
        {9, 5, 1},
        {_, _, _}
    }
    {
        {_, _, _},
        {_, _, _},
        {4, 3, 8}
    }
```

By the way, you could test the diagonals as well. For the first diagonal, the indices are equal. For the second diagonal, one is the difference between the other and the max index.

```
For rowcol As Integer = 0 To 2
    columnTotal += magicSquare(rowcol, rowcol)
Next
MsgBox("First diagonal " & columnTotal)
columnTotal = 0
For rowcol As Integer = 0 To 2
    columnTotal += magicSquare(rowcol, 2 - rowcol)
Next
MsgBox("Second diagonal " & columnTotal)
```

Comment: As an aside, beware that array layout is opposite in VBA and COM (they're column-major instead of row-major)---which is a way, as in a lot of other areas, VBA is a lot more similar to Fortran than to C-heritage languages.

Comment: @Craig I didn't realize that about VBA. This might explain the use of `MsgBox` in the question as well. I will point it out in my answer. Thanks and go B's!

Comment: It should be noted that the main issue here is efficiency.  If you treat a VBA array as if it were row-major throughout your program, the only issue will be that you'll have issues with cache usage if the array is too big to fit in a single cache line (and even if this happens, unless the code is data-intensive with pretty large arrays, you probably wouldn't notice the difference).  It only becomes an issue in interop scenarios; passing a two+-dimension array as a block of memory between .NET and VBA may have surprising results.